# Why did I get 11 reputation points and no downvotes for my answer?

Tags: discussion

How did I get 11 reputation points for a single question’s answer?

Comment: Adding a link to the answer in question (haha) would help. Was it this one? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/219687/floor-strength-help/219689#219689

Comment: @NiallC. Yes, it was the first upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a limit of 200 rep points per day (see [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)), excluding the 15 points for an accepted answer, or any bounties that you might get, and it looks like you hit it yesterday.

Take a look at the entry for March 25th on the [reputation tab on your user profile](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/66548/lee-sam?tab=reputation&sort=post). You'll see a slightly different view from everyone else, but I see (as will other users):

- +190 for [Is straight lumber a thing of the past?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/219625/is-straight-lumber-a-thing-of-the-past/219631#219631) from 19 upvotes.
- +13/-2 for [Floor strength help](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/219687/floor-strength-help/219689#219689). One downvote, the -2, followed by two upvotes: +10 for the first, then +3 for the second because of the reputation cap.
- nothing for [Why did the builder install an OSB Wall behind Drywall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/143698/why-did-the-builder-install-an-osb-wall-behind-drywall/143713#143713). This didn't earn you any points because you'd already hit the 200 point limit for the day.

"But that page shows I have 201 points for the day. What about that extra point?", you say. Possibly related to downvotes on answers that you cast during the day, or downvotes that you removed during the day, or posts that you previously downvoted being deleted, but only you can see that extra information.

The order of the reputation changes is significant as well. You could get 1000 upvotes on an answer, but you'll get capped at 200 points. Then if a downvote comes in just before midnight, you'll end up with 198 points for the day.

Comment: It’s too complicated for me. Thanks for looking into it.